# iterate all nodes in a path and comparing the property in adjacent nodes to output only the ones that match a certain conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's assume I have a path A(wt=80)->B(wt=100)->C(wt=110)->D(wt=160)->E(wt=170)
I want to find out all the nodes in this path that has difference of wt>=20. in this case it should only give me B and D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first get the start node and the end node of each relationship, and then use "Where" to return the end nodes of those relationships whose end nodes satisfy the difference condition, something like this,

```
Match p = a-[:Rel*]->e
Where a.name?='A'
With endNode(last(relationships(p))) as second, startNode(last(relationships(p))) as first
Where second.wt - first.wt >= 20
Return second
```

Comment: I use the following data to test out CREATE (A {name:'A', wt:80})
CREATE (B {name:'B', wt:100})
CREATE (C {name:'C', wt:110})
CREATE (D {name:'D', wt:160})
CREATE (E {name:'E', wt:170})

CREATE
   (A)-[:Rel]->(B),
   (B)-[:Rel]->(C),
   (C)-[:Rel]->(D),
   (D)-[:Rel]->(E)
; and try to use the following start a=node(*)
Match p = a-[:Rel*]->e
Where a.name?='A'
With endNode(last(rels(p))) as second, startNode(last(rels(p))) as first
Where second.wt - first.wt >= 20
Return second, but I get a syntax error.